# Always get the id of the last iteration ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to select an id using a onClick method, the only problem is that when i click a button only the last id is displayed.

```
const renderTableData = () => {
let id = 0;
return (
  <tr>
    {days.map((val) => (
      <td>
        {timeSlot.map((time, i) => {
          if (occupiedSlots().result.includes(id + 1)) {
            return (
              <button id={id++} className="disabledButton">
                {time}
              </button>
            );
          } else {
            return (
              <button id={id++} className="activeButton" onClick ={() => {canBookSlot({id})}}> 
                {time}
              </button>
            );
          }
        })}
      </td>
    ))}
  </tr>
);
};
```

This is what the `canBookSlot()` function looks like:

```
 const canBookSlot = (id) => {
let userDetailsString = localStorage.getItem("userDetails");
const userDetailsObj = JSON.parse(userDetailsString)

if(userDetailsObj.canBook != 0){
      Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/book/week1/ex', {
         room: userDetailsObj.room,
         id: id
    })

    return console.log(id) 
} else {
  return console.log("somethings wrong")
}
```

};

The output is always 70. how do i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider your variable called `days` - if something else did `days = null;` you would expect your `days.map` to fail when it next renders. `id` is no different - *every* button is using the same id variable, so when you increase it, all usage of that value will witness that increase too.

So, you need to "capture" the current value of id for a given button. Due to [the way how scope works in JS](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp), a function body has its own set of variables. Because you are inside the function callback of `map`, that means we can define a buttonId variable inside it, and it will naturally be per button:

```
const renderTableData = () => {
let id = 0;
return (
  <tr>
    {days.map((val) => (
      <td>
        {timeSlot.map((time, i) => {
          var buttonId = id++;
          if (occupiedSlots().result.includes(buttonId + 1)) {
            return (
              <button id={buttonId} className="disabledButton">
                {time}
              </button>
            );
          } else {
            return (
              <button id={buttonId} className="activeButton" onClick ={() => {canBookSlot({id: buttonId})}}> 
                {time}
              </button>
            );
          }
        })}
      </td>
    ))}
  </tr>
);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`id` is a global variable, and react itself has no idea of, everytime your table renders a button:

```
<button id={id++}> </button>
```

The value of `id` increases by `id++`. And after the whole table gets rendered, the final value of `id` got incremented to the total length of the whole 2d array - 70. (I'm pretty sure you've disabled `strickMode`, otherwise the value could've doubled.)

So, that's the reason why you'll always get the last id. There're several ways to solve this, but the key is to understand why react use `key prop` for rendering array in the first place, for more detailed explanation, you can [look up this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43892905/16648127).

Comment: Ahh okey that makes sense, i looked at the link but I'm not able to find an answer to this problem only the importance of having a unique key.

Comment: @MaxAndersson the problem you're having is unrelated to having a unique key :)

Comment: I know, i was refering to the link. I get 70 unique keys the problem is as mentioned that react only stores the final value of `id`